# Slow Performance of Levenshtein distance formula in large database

Tags: mysql

I used this query for searching company details

```
select * 
from company_details 
where levenshtein_ratio('New York Life Insurance Company',`cmp_name`) > 50
```

But it is too slow it gets records after 1 or 2 minutes some time.

Comment: What is your `levenshtein_ratio` stored function code your asking us to optimise something you have not shown to us?

Comment: You know the levenshtein algorithm have complexity N*M.

Comment: How many rows you have in the table? What's the average string length of 'cmp_name'. Is it possible to see an EXPLAIN?